# Monitoring tool in Amazon Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

In DB2 we have `db2top` which help to monitor the Database activities.

Is there any equivalent available in Amazon Redshift?

Comment: In real PostgreSQL people use `pgtop`. No idea if it works with Redshift.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried pgtop (http://search.cpan.org/dist/pgtop/pgtop) and it does work for Redshift, but I don't find it particularly useful since Redshift isn't handling transactional traffic.  I'll usually use

```
select * from SVV_QUERY_INFLIGHT order by query, sequence;
```

or

```
select pid, user_name, starttime, query from stv_recents where status='Running';
```

to show current activity.  You can use

```
select relation::regclass, mode, pid from pg_locks where locktype != 'virtualxid' ;
```

to show locks.  I also like

```
select * from stv_wlm_query_state where queue_time > 0;
```

to show if there's been queue contention, implying we need to potentially adjust WLM configuration.  One other query that I like is

```
select query, step, rows, workmem, label, is_diskbased from svl_query_summary;
```

most notably because I want to know if a query is having to write to disk implying not enough memory.  Outside of using Cloudwatch alerts for CPU and disk usage, regular monitoring for us is more oriented toward analysis of table structure.  Use the script in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_analyzing-table-design.html to do that analysis and vaccum and analyze regularly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in monitoring hardware metrics (CPU, Disk Space, Read/Write IOPs/Latency/Throughput), these could be viewed on the cloudwatch console provided by AWS.

AWS also provides a dashboard to monitor running and completed queries. However, in my experience, it doesn't show all of them making debugging performance issues quite challenging. A few useful aggregate metrics that you may want to collect and store could be:

1. **Queries fired per user**: Plotting the above data could help in spotting anomalies in cluster usage by a specific user

   ```
              SELECT * FROM stv_recents WHERE status = 'Running';
   ```
2. **Count of queries and average time taken in Queued/Running/Returning State**: If the average time in 'running' state is very high in 1 queue it may be impacting the performance of queries in other queues as well. (This occurs as WLM settings only allow cap on memory usage and CPU utilization)

   ```
              SELECT * FROM stv_wlm_query_state;
   ```
3. **Identify bad queries**: While identifying poorly written queries is not straightforward until after its finished executing (at least in my experience), a few proxies could help weed out bad queries while they are still executing. A higher *number of diskhits* and *rows broadcast* across nodes are such indicators. The following query will provide this data.

   ```
   SELECT wlm.query AS query_id,
          wlm.state,
          wlm.service_class AS queue,
          CONVERT_TIMEZONE('Asia/Calcutta',wlm.wlm_start_time) AS starttime,
          wlm.slot_count,
          pg_user.usename AS username,
          ex.inner_bcast_count,
          bcast.bcast_rows,
          CAST((wlm.exec_time) AS float) / 1000000 AS exec_time,
          CAST((wlm.queue_time) AS float) / 1000000 AS queue_time,
          CAST(SUM(qs.workmem) AS float) / 1000000000 AS workmem,
          SUM(CASE WHEN qs.is_diskbased = 't' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_diskhits
          FROM stv_wlm_query_state wlm
           LEFT JOIN svv_query_state qs ON qs.query = wlm.query
           LEFT JOIN pg_user ON qs.userid = pg_user.usesysid
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT query, 
                          SUM(ROWS) AS bcast_rows
                      FROM stl_bcast
                      GROUP BY 1) bcast ON bcast.query = wlm.query
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ex.query,
                      COUNT(*) inner_bcast_count
                      FROM stl_explain ex,
                      stv_wlm_query_state wlm
                      WHERE wlm.query = ex.query
                      AND   wlm.state = 'Running'
                      AND   ex.plannode LIKE ('%%DS_BCAST_INNER%%')
                      GROUP BY 1) ex ON ex.query = wlm.query
   GROUP BY 1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10
   ```

As pointed out in another answer, the best way is to build custom tools to collect and monitor these metrics and any others that you would want to track for your RedShift usage.

You could check out [RedEye](https://github.com/myntra/RedEye). It will require a pre installed instance of Statsd and MySQL. The tool collects a set of metrics across hardware and query performance and stores it in the above databases.

Comment: I have edited my answer to share some of the queries and rationale behind the tool. Hope this adheres to the rules. I am new to this so thanks for your advice. :)